# Python Schedule вызывает функцию сразу, а не по расписанию

Tags: python, schedule

У меня есть код, который парсит файлы с сайта, а затем их объединяет. Его нужно выполнять каждый день в определенное время. Узнал про Schedule и подумал, что это может оптимизировать мне процесс, но код просто запускается как и всегда, не обращая внимания на установленное расписание. Вроде прописал все условия, гуглил, но ничего не нашел. Подскажите пожалуйста!

```
import schedule, time, pathlib, requests, pendulum, json, shutil
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import auto
from datetime import date, timedelta


def download_reports(credentials_file_path,
                    begin_date,
                    end_date,
                    output_directory_path=None):
    credentials = pd.read_excel(credentials_file_path)
    usernames = credentials['username'].tolist()
    passwords = credentials['password'].tolist()
    begin_date = pendulum.from_format(begin_date,
                                        'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    end_date = pendulum.from_format(end_date,
                                    'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    for username, password in auto.tqdm(zip(usernames, passwords),
                                        total=len(usernames)):
        try:
            ...

        except Exception as exception:
            ...
    merge_excels(directory_path = 'downloaded_reports',
                 begin_date = begin_date,
                 end_date = end_date)


def merge_excels(directory_path,
                    begin_date,
                    end_date,
                    file_path=None):
    ...
    return dataframe



def main():
    schedule.every().day.at('11:30').do(download_reports('credentials.xlsx', 
                                                         begin_date = str(date.today() - timedelta(days = 1)), 
                                                         end_date = str(date.today())))
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Условно, я запускаю скрипт в 11:25, а в Schedule прописываю 11:30, но код выполняется сразу же, не дожидаясь нужного времени

Comment: Так вы в `do` отдаете результат вывова функции, а надо саму функцию и ее аргументы. [pass-arguments-to-a-job](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#pass-arguments-to-a-job)

Comment: @user207200 То есть мне нужно просто прописать: `schedule.every().day.at('11:30').do(download_reports)` а аргументы передать внутри функции?

Comment: @user207200 Ааа, все, понял, спасибо большое! Правильный код : `schedule.every().day.at('12:20').do(download_reports, credentials_file_path = 'credentials1.xlsx',  begin_date = str(date.today() - timedelta(days = 1)), end_date = str(date.today()))`